# Render image using React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am writing a code to render an image, returned as an api response as a byte array, on to my browser. If I invoke the api directly, I can see the image, but am not able to render it using react. Below is my code snippet to fetch the byte array

```
ScreenShareService.subscribe("SRJ1001").then(data => { // This fetches the byte array
            console.log('ComponentDidMount '+this.state.image) // this is printing the byte array
            this.setState({image: data.data})
        })
    .catch(
        (err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        }
    )

render(){
    return(
        <>
        <div>
            {this.state.image}
        </div>
             </>
    );
}
```

Please assist

Comment: Try `<div><img src={[backtick]data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.image}[backtick]} /></div>`

change [backtick] with `

Comment: no, not working